# Reload recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android and I am having a problem reloading (rebuilding) as recyclerview after the activity is active.  The activity with the recyclerview is a second activity started as an intent on the main activity. I can load it up, and show a list of items.  When one of the items is clicked a third activity is launched.  The problem is sometimes there are too many items on the list.  I want to add a way of selecting an item more easily.  I added a spinner on the same activity as the recyclerview.  When an item is selected on the spinner, I want to reload a shorter version of the list, based on the spinner selection.  However, I can't find a way to achieve that.  Any help or suggestions pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing your code, no one can effectively help you.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind suggestions.  I got it solve by calling the removeAllViews() and then notifyDataSetChanged() methods.

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer as accepted to help others too.

Answer (score 0):

as @bink said without code it's hard to help, but the idea in general is that on your `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` you populate your recyclerView, so everytime you change the selection you get a new list depending on the choosed value.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ArrayList<> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            // add your items based on item spinner.itemSelected
            // for(---)
            adapter = new MyAdapter(context, arrayList );
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
           
        });
```

- You can also add a filter to your recycler view (https://medium.com/android-news/filterable-recyclerview-in-android-the-how-to-a9ade9cd26)
- If you dont want to recreate all the recycler view and the list itselft, use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`